# Curl/PHP challenge transferring image and base64_encode/decode

Tags: php, curl

I am transfering data from one linux-box to another. In generel this works fine, BUT I am having trouble when it comes to transferring images. I have tested all kinds of stuff. I hope some one may be able to help me out.

```
    $filename  = "/home/user/image.jpg";
    $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
    $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    $data      = base64_encode($data);

    # Transfer reading
    #$arrIn['changeCharset'] = "true";
    $arrIn['postFields'] = "action=test&data=$base64";
    $test = curlServerPost($arrIn);
```

Here is my CURL-function:

```
function curlServerPost($arrIn)
{
    $postFields = $arrIn['postFields'];
    $url = "$GLOBALS[remoteSite]"; // Where you want to post data

    $ch = curl_init(); // Initiate cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // Tell cURL you want to post something
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields); // Define what you want to post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return the output in string format
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepter alle certifikater, se: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/
    $res = curl_exec($ch); // Execute

    curl_close($ch); // Close cURL handle
    return($res);
}
```

Finally, here is the receiver (server) part

```
$data = $_POST[data];
$data = base64_decode($data);

$stmt = $GLOBALS[pdo]->prepare("INSERT INTO cameraImages (cameraImagesId) VALUES ('')");
$stmt->execute();
$cameraImagesId = $GLOBALS[pdo]->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $GLOBALS[pdo]->prepare("UPDATE cameraImages SET cameraImagesFile='$data' WHERE cameraImagesId='$cameraImagesId'");
$stmt->execute();
```

Some last remarks:
- If I don't base_decode on server-side I receive (but completely wrong format. Errors in image)

- If I base_decode om server-side. Nothing is received.
- I would like to don't encode/decode at all. If I do that. Only a small part of the image is stored (corrupted image)
- My datafield is LONGBLOB (mysql)
- PHP on server side is: PHP 5.3.3
- PHP on client side is: PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u1

I have tried all kinds of stuff. Followed all kinds of tutorials. It just won't work for me :-/

So if anyone can come up with ideas I am more than willing to test and try :)

Loooking forward to hear from you.

Comment: why dont you just use scp to copy the files across?

Comment: _“I would like to don't encode/decode at all. If I do that. Only a small part of the image is stored (corrupted image)”_ - that’s most likely because you assembled the form data “manually”, using string concatenation, and didn’t pay attention to what special characters might need escaping at all ... keyword URL encoding.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean concerning the encoding special character encoding. The image is image/jpeg; charset=binary. But well I am trying to get help here. Should I escape chars in curl when tranferring an image?

Comment: Concerning scp....true I could do that, I was considering FTP too, but I have a complete setup with Curl so I would prefer to continue doing that.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succes. I just needed

```
urlencode($data);
```

And removed base64_encode($data); / base64_decode($data);
I have dropped putting images in database since many ppl don't recommend it.

Comment: this is not good Idea of upload file in Database. it will slow down your database..